# Problem with toggle function with table with dynamically named ids

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, dynamic, toggle

I'm quite new in web development and first time trying to code a Wordpress plugin from the scratch. I'm aiming to have a table on which clicking a row will open additional information in few rows. The rows' ids are named dynamically (baserow + post's id and subrow + post's id). For some reason, only the first row will toggle when clicked and the others do not react in any way. I have tried to google for an answer but couldn't find one. So, hoping that here someone might be able to help. Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

**.php file**

```
<?php 

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'ecalendar-event',
  'orderby' => '_ecalendar_meta_date',
'order' => 'ASC',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'ecalendar_category',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'kek'
    )
  )
);
$kek_events = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $kek_events->have_posts() ) {
  while( $kek_events->have_posts() ) {
    $kek_events->the_post();
    $id =  'subrow'.$post->ID;
    $bid = 'baserow'.$post->ID;
       ?>
       
       <tr id="<?php echo $bid;?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="baserow_id" value="<?php echo $bid ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="subrow_id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">

        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_date_formatted', true);?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_place', true);?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_class', true);?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_organizer', true);?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_status', true);?></td>
       </tr>

        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Paikka</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_address', true);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Ylituomari</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_first_judge', true);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Palkintotuomari</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_second_judge', true);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Rajoitukset</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_limit', true);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Etusija</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_priority', true);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Ilm.aika</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_enrollment1', true);?>-<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_enrollment1', true);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Os.maksu</td>
            <td colspan="3">Yleinen: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_price1', true);?>€, Jäsenille: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_price2', true);?>€</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id ="<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;"> 
            <td colspan="2">Lisätiedot</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_info', true);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Muuta</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_other', true);?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <td colspan="2">Tiedustelut</td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ecalendar_meta_contact', true);?></td>
       </tr><?php 

    }
  }

  wp_reset_postdata()

 ?>
```

**.js file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('table#kek-kokeet tbody tr#'+jQuery('#baserow_id').val()).click(function() {
        
        jQuery('table#kek-kokeet tbody tr#'+jQuery('#subrow_id').val()).toggle(400);
    });

});
```

Comment: Because Id must be unique, so why your code only toggle 1st row.

Comment: And another aspect in which the HTML you are creating there is invalid - you can not just put input fields as children of a table row, they need to go into one of the table _cells_.

Comment: 4b0: All the post have their own id:s which are constructed with subrow+post's id. So in this case the first row has ids: baserow79 and subrow79. The second row gets ids baserow80 and subrow80. Doesn't this make them unique? 

CBroe: Thank you for advice! I'll correct my code.